# Automatically connecting Bluetooth LE keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Tablet gen 2.  I recently bought a Lenovo Trackpoint Keyboard II which uses Bluetooth LE.  Using a [Stack Exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678573/how-to-pair-a-ble-device-in-linux-without-using-gatttool), I was able to get the Bluetooth LE keyboard working with

```
sudo -i 
btmgmt power off
btmgmt discov on
btmgmt connectable on
btmgmt pairable on
btmgmt power on
bluetoothctl --agent KeyboardDisplay
```

and then

```
pair 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

But currently I have to do this each time I want to use the keyboard.  Is there a way of automating Bluetooth LE connections, like normal Bluetooth connections, so that when I turn the keyboard on the computer connects to it?